# R: aggregate by date - (every 30min mean)

Tags: r, aggregate

I have been struggling with this for a while now:
I have a data frame that contains 5-minute measurements (for around 6 months) of different parameters. I want to aggregate them and get the mean of every parameter every 30 min. Here is a short example:

```
TIMESTAMP <- c("2015-12-31 0:30", "2015-12-31 0:35","2015-12-31 0:40", "2015-12-31 0:45", "2015-12-31 0:50", "2015-12-31 0:55", "2015-12-31 1:00", "2015-12-31 1:05", "2015-12-31 1:10", "2015-12-31 1:15", "2015-12-31 1:20", "2015-12-31 1:25", "2015-12-31 1:30")
value1 <- c(45, 50, 68, 78, 99, 100, 5, 9, 344, 10, 45, 68, 33)
mymet <- as.data.frame(TIMESTAMP, value1)
mymet$TIMESTAMP <- as.POSIXct(mymet$TIMESTAMP, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")

halfhour <- aggregate(mymet, list(TIME = cut(mymet$TIMESTAMP, breaks = "30 mins")), 
  mean, na.rm = TRUE)
```

What I want to get is the average between 00:35 and 1:00 and call this DATE-1:00AM, however, what I get is: average between 00:30 and 00:55 and this is called DATE-12:30am.

How can I change the function to give me the values that I want?

Comment: Is the code you ran the same as the code in the question? Because there are minor problems with this code which prevent it from running.

Comment: What do you mean "and this is called DATE-12:30am"? I don't see any variable called `DATE` in the code or output. Right now this question is unclear. Perhaps if you could add a formatted example of your expected results using this example data.

Comment: I'd try playing with the "cut" function. In particular, with "include.lowest" and "right" parameters, which should control if you get "open" or "closed" intervals on the two sides. default seems to be open on the left and closed on the right, and that would be coherent with the "behaviour" you described.

Comment: I created the dataframe real quick just to give an example, it is different from the original one...but the code is pretty much the same. What I meant as output is that the generated timestamp says TIMESTAMP: 2015-12-31 0:30 and the average for value1 is taken from the values (45, 50, 68, 78, 99)  What I want is: TIMESTAMP 2015-12-31 1:00 and the average for value1 from (50, 68, 78, 99, 100)

Comment: @LorenzoBusetto Thanks! this solved the problem!!

Answer (score 1):

The trick (I think) is looking at when your first observation starts. If the first observation is 00:35 and you do the 30 minute cut then the intervals should follow the logic you want. Regarding the name of the Breaks it's just a matter of adding 25 minutes to the name and then you get what you want. Here is an example for 6 months of 2015:

```
require(lubridate)
require(dplyr)
TIMESTAMP <- seq(ymd_hm('2015-01-01 00:00'),ymd_hm('2015-06-01 23:55'), by = '5 min')
TIMESTAMP <- data.frame(obs=1:length(TIMESTAMP),TS=TIMESTAMP)
TIMESTAMP <- TIMESTAMP[-(1:7),] #TO start with at 00:35 minutes
TIMESTAMP$Breaks <- cut(TIMESTAMP$TS, breaks = "30 mins")
TIMESTAMP$Breaks <- ymd_hms(as.character(TIMESTAMP$Breaks)) + (25*60)
Averages <- TIMESTAMP %>% group_by(Breaks) %>%    summarise(MeanObs=mean(obs,na.rm = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you get `mymet` constructed properly, you can cut `TIMESTAMP` into bins (which you can do with `cut.POSIXt`) so you can `aggregate`:

```
mymet$half_hour <- cut(mymet$TIMESTAMP, breaks = "30 min")

aggregate(value1 ~ half_hour, mymet, mean)

##             half_hour   value1
## 1 2015-12-31 00:30:00 73.33333
## 2 2015-12-31 01:00:00 80.16667
## 3 2015-12-31 01:30:00 33.00000
```

---

#### Data

```
mymet <- structure(list(TIMESTAMP = structure(c(1451539800, 1451540100, 
    1451540400, 1451540700, 1451541000, 1451541300, 1451541600, 1451541900, 
    1451542200, 1451542500, 1451542800, 1451543100, 1451543400), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), value1 = c(45, 50, 68, 78, 99, 100, 5, 
    9, 344, 10, 45, 68, 33)), .Names = c("TIMESTAMP", "value1"), row.names = c(NA, 
    -13L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: thanks! my data already exists as a .csv, the timestamp is automatically generated by an instrument, along with the other values. I (poorly) created this dataframe just for show. My initial code works for getting the mean, but my problem are the intervals that are chosen to get the mean